# How to decrypt a right shifted message with XOR?

Tags: logical-operators, bit-shift

I have a message m that I encrypt by the code
c = m xor [m>>1]
(m>>x means that I shift it by x bits - eg 1000>>1 = 0100)

I need to decrypt this message.

I have tried code like for 6 but its Not working for 1 bit shift:

```
int main() {
    uint32_t n = 0xff;
    for (uint32_t m = 0; m < n; ++m) {
         printf("input: %X \n", m); 
        uint32_t c = m ^ (m >> 6);// c = encrypted value
        printf("encrypted value: %X \n", m);
        uint32_t x = c;
        x ^= ((x &       0x3F) >> 6);
        x ^= ((x &      0xFC0) >> 6);
        x ^= ((x &    0x3F000) >> 6);
        x ^= ((x &   0xFC0000) >> 6);
        x ^= ((x & 0x3F000000) >> 6);
        if (m != x) {
            printf("Mismatch: %X > %X > %X\n", m, c, x); // should never happen
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A xor-shift with a right-shift by 1 bit can be undone like this:

```
x ^= x >> 1;
x ^= x >> 2;
x ^= x >> 4;
x ^= x >> 8;
x ^= x >> 16;
```

A xor-shift with a right-shift by 6 can be undone like you showed, but also like this, which is shorter:

```
x ^= (x >> 6) ^ (x >> 12);
x ^= x >> 18;
```